# Connecting laptop to desktop computer without VGA/HDMI to share screen

Tags: display, connection

Can I connect my laptop (MacBook Air) to external desktop computer (HP) without using VGA or HDMI since my Desktop computer has only USB port?

My ultimate goal is to represent laptop screen on my desktop computer screen.

Comment: You can't represent your laptop screen on your desktop monitors by connecting it to your desktop computer; you can use your laptop as a monitor screen for your desktop, or use VGA/DVI/HDMI to connect your laptop to the external monitors used for your desktop.

Comment: Is the question essentially asking if you can use the desktop monitor for the laptop?

Comment: You can use remote desktop software.  If you install realvnc server on the macbook, you can connect to it from your desktop using realvnc client.  This stream data over the network, so 3D graphics may be slow or appear to be skipping.  Other companies also make this kind of software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect your MacBook Air to your HP computer as long as the computer can capture an input (via a expansion card, etc.). You can then display your screen with any software that is able to display inputs. OR the simplest way to go on about doing this is to connect your desktop monitor directly into the MacBoook Air. This is by far the easiest and the fastest way.

[image]

Either way, you will need a mini display port to HDMI, VGA, or DVI connector whichever your monitor/capture card supports.